# How can I disable all audio output from my OSX machine when the screen is locked

Tags: macos, audio, sleep-wake

Essentially, I often forget to turn the sound down/off when leaving my OSX machine for the day. Since my computer is in my living room, I inevitably get a notification of some kind while watching TV, and have to laboriously get up and turn the sound off.

(Note that I basically never shut it down, I always just use a sleep corner.)

Is there a setting for disabling audio output entirely when the computer is asleep?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out you can do this with the "Do not Disturb" feature in System Preferences -> Notifications. I actually had it turned on, but had the checkbox with "From XXX to YYY" time checked. I unchecked that, and made sure the "When the display is sleeping" was checked, and that seems to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Option + Click on the Notification Center icon (the latest on the right in the bar) in Menu Bar will disable all kind of notification.

Here's the official article [Turn off notifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18740?locale=en_US)